# What is the difference between an analytical standard and a certified reference material?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, terminology

I am analysing the analytical standard market, but every time I try to understand what an analytical standard is, I only get the definition of a certified reference material. Is there a difference?

Comment: An analytical standard (as I understand it) is a defined amount of analytical reagent (EDTA, phosphate, iron, cer, etc.) that you can flush into a calibrated flask that you then fill up to the marking where it has it's defined volume, and you have a solution with defined "guaranteed" concentration, e.g. for titration. Does that fit to what *you* think it is?

Comment: I don't think you find any universally recognized definitions for the two terms. In essence an "analytical standard" has to be certified by  some organization/company. So to me the terms are essentially the same. Exactly how you use the standard would depend on what the standard sample was. You can have a certified weight, a set of steel standards for XRF, or KHP for acid/base titrations.

Answer (score 2):

An analytical standard is a compound of suitable purity and known concentration to be used as a calibration standard for an assay.

A certified reference material is a material which has been certified by some trusted organisation to be of a consistent quality and composition. Normally, but not always, the concentrations of the major components of a CRM have been carefully measured. For example, the [US-NIST](https://www.nist.gov/srm) produce hundreds of reference materials for everything from limestone to baking chocolate to dried human lung tissue. Labs analysing these materials use the reference material as a quality control to check that they are consistent with other labs.